# RN0.26 Debug JS Remotely freezes app

Tags: debugging, react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I recently upgraded react native from 0.24 to 0.26.2.  My app ran and debugged in chrome fine before.  Since upgrading to 0.26.2, my app runs fine, but when I try to 'Debug JS Remotely' it freezes up. Has anyone else experienced this or come up with a solution?

Not sure what relevant code to share.  Here is package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-lock": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.26.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-persist": "^3.1.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also receiving this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing RCTBatchedBridge.m with the version in 0.25.1
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.25-stable/React/Base/RCTBatchedBridge.m fixed it for me.

here is the GH discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7635

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue today, also updating from 0.24 to 0.26.2.

My error was: my native binaries had been built against react-native@0.26.2, and react@0.14.8.

After updating to the required version react@15.0.2, wiping my build artifacts, and rebuilding, the problem went away.

Comment: glad you got it working.  what steps did you take to clear your build artifacts?  I deleted Derived Data but app still freezes.  thanks!

Comment: also tried ctrl+option+shift+k to clear build artifacts.  issue persists, did you do anything else?